# How can I build a Yocto SDK for a different architecture?

Tags: yocto

I would like to build a Yocto SDK for both x86_64 and aarch64, using one Linux computer if possible.

I have built a standard Yocto SDK for my system's architecture (x86_64) using `bitbake <image> -c populate_sdk`, and it works great. I want to run the SDK in a container (like https://github.com/crops/extsdk-container/), and I would like it to work on an ARM-based Mac for other developers.
Obviously the x86_64 SDK installer won't run in a standard container on the arm-based Mac, since the container architecture won't match the installer.

I haven't been able to find any options for specifying a different architecture when doing populate_sdk. It's looking like I will have to get the full yocto setup on my M1 Mac and build the SDK from there, and then have to maintain two SDK installers, which isn't ideal.

Does anyone know how to do this?

If I have to run the container under QEMU or something, I don't think I want to keep going down this road...

Comment: Just a vague thought: have tried changing the `BUILD_SYS` (and maybe `BUILD_ARCH`) variable while building the sdk to the desired arch?

Comment: I tried setting BUILD_SYS and BUILD_ARCH before the bitbake command, and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I am working with a Yocto BSP from NXP, and I saw a note on a support page: "We don't support aarch64 sdk for machine". So it doesn't seem possible to do what I was hoping to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build the aarch64 SDK installer for my target machine by updating the bitbake config located at `/oe-core/meta/conf/bitbake.conf`

There is a hardcoded line `SDKMACHINE ??= "x86_64"` and all I had to do is to change it to `SDKMACHINE ??= "aarch64"` and rerun the SDK build.

Not sure if that's applicable to all target machines though.